# Message and MMS logging

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, sms, mms

I want to make application which can fetch the sms from inbox,outbox and draft and also MMS data which is there in phone memory or External i.e memory card of the phone.

I had try to do it b using http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.ph...idge_Interface.

But I am getting the bridge exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access inbox, outbox, draft and MMS using J2ME. So you can't achieve with j2me. There is no API available for that.